# a href not working and not resizing

Tags: html, css

My a href inside a div is not working I saw that the width and height was 0px, so I tried to increase size, but it doesn't get increased.
Each dot is supposed to send you to another page in the onepage scroller I'm making

```css
.dotstyle-scaleup{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 3%;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup li{
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 80px 0 0 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup #current1{
 background-color: #54a59f;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 80px 0 0 0;
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Landings -->
        <div class="section"  data-anchor="page1" style="background-color: red">
          <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
            <ul>
              <li id="current1"><a href="#page1"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page2"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page5"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are floating your whole `div` to right.

Comment: `<a>` is inline element you should put some content inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the elements in question contain no content, declaring `height` and `width` properties won't be enough.

Consider declaring a `display` property, in addition to specifying a `height` and `width` property for the nested anchor elements (`a`) e.g:

```
.dotstyle-scaleup li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.dotstyle-scaleup {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup li {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.dotstyle-scaleup #current1 {
  background-color: #54a59f;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Additional */

.dotstyle-scaleup li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Landings -->
  <div class="section" data-anchor="page1" style="background-color: red">
    <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
      <ul>
        <li id="current1">
          <a href="#page1"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page2"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page3"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page4"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#page5"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have a answer about my dot navigation, if you look good you can see that the highlighted dot is not aligned with the other four, how can I aligned it?

Comment: @CodePirate Since it is `5px` larger than the inactive dots, the easiest thing to do would be to offset that size difference with a negative value `margin` property, like: `.dotstyle-scaleup #current1 {
    margin-left: -2.5px;
}`